# 14/3 for dual 120 appliance

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am running 15 amps to a furnace that uses 2 separate 15 amp 120V circuits.  240V is not used.  Is 14/3 adequate?  Is a 14 gauge return good enough for both poles?

Comment: Is there a label on the furnace that states the wattage/amperage of the two circuits?  What do the installation instructions say to use?

Comment: I would be checking with local state regulations. In my jurisdiction furnaces are required to have dedicated 20 amp, yes they can be MWBC’s but 12-3 with ground is required for things like the furnace and electrostatic filter for example both hard wired.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking at a multi wired branch circuit where two legs on separate phases share a neutral. They are allowed but require a double pole breaker or handle tied single breakers. If you're running this to a single point, an outlet junction box,then 14/3 would be OK. If you're running it to separate locations on the furnace, I'd be running separate 14/2 runs on single breakers.

Furnaces are usually in confined spaces or basements and the cables used have to be protected. Are you sure you want to run cable and not EMT conduit and pull wire or use FMC? Are you even allowed to run NB cable?
Check your instructions that are included with the furnace.

Answer (score 2):

Current flows in loops. Neutral is the return current path.  You are correct that #14 neutral can't handle any more amps than #14 hot (15A) and obviously, *two* hots returning 15A *each* will set a shared neutral on fire.

However, thanks to split-phase power, there's a funny exception if you "phase" the hot wires *exactly right*.   If the two hot wires are 180 degrees out of phase (or even 120 degrees in 3-phase power), then the neutral wire will only carry *differential* current.   *E.G. If the loads are 10A and 8A then 8A will flow from hot 1 through both loads to hot 2, and won't go through neutral at all.  Only 2A will be on neutral.*   You will know if the two hots are 180 degrees out-of-phase because there will be 240 volts between them.  (or 208V in 3-phase land).  That high voltage between them is the correct situation for a shared neutral.  This technique is called "Multi-Wire Branch Circuit".

Note also that the 2 breakers on the MWBC must be *handle-tied* to assure a maintainer turns off both halves of the circuit at once.  Also, you cannot use devices to splice the neutral. Neutrals must be pigtailed.

However, **they are largely obsolete and for good reason**.  With increasing requirements for AFCI or GFCI protection on circuits, protection which must often be at the breaker, that usually does not play well with a shared neutral.  It forces you into costly $100 GFCI or AFCI breakers.  As such I am very reluctant to advise anyone plan to use MWBCs.